# Ruby on Rails count objects within objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following query that counts the number of visits a household makes each month to my agency

```
visits.by_month(@month).select("DISTINCT(household_id)").count
```

This returns the number of households visiting each month

But each household has many neighbors in a separate model so: household.neighbors.count gives me the number of neighbors in the household but I want all the neighbors for all the households

In other words I want a count of the total neighbors for all the households that visited in a particular month and their ages:

In my neighbors model I have scope for my age groups:

```
scope :young, where( 'age < 19')
scope :middle, where('age > 18 && age < 66')
scope :old, where('age > 65')
```

How do I return the count of neighbors visiting each month by age group?:

or:

```
Jones Household   {Bob: 14, Sally: 30, Stan: 80}
Smith Household {Ben: 30, Sue 15}

Total Households   2
Total Neighbors served: 5 
Total Young Neighbors:  2
Total Middle Neighbors: 2
Total Old Neighbors:    1
```

I started with this but this is wrong:

```
visits.by_month(@month).select("DISTINCT(household_id)").each.neighbors.count
```

Any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am fully understanding the question, but how about this:

```
# get an array of all distinct household IDs for that month
household_ids = visits.by_month(@month).pluck(:household_id).uniq

household_ids.each do |h_id|
  young_count  = visits.by_month(@month).where(:household_id=>h_id).young.count
  middle_count = visits.by_month(@month).where(:household_id=>h_id).middle.count
  old_count    = visits.by_month(@month).where(:household_id=>h_id).old.count
  puts "Number of young people visiting from household: #{h_id} is #{young_count}"
end
```

If this is not what you was expecting, maybe pasting some more of your model code might help. I don't think I am 100% on what you expect your outcome to be.

Comment: I agree it was an unclear question so I clarified it - hope this helps

Comment: I think the answer is in flipping the query to a query on neighbors with something like neighbors.where(:h_id=>:houshold_id).young.count